# PHP syntax ?? meaning,can somebody explain?

Tags: php

I've seen this code and I don`'t know what does it mean

```
$page = $_GET['page'] ?? 'home';
```

Can somebody tell me its meaning?

Comment: It's the [Null Coalescence Operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)

Comment: I bet a one minute test would give you the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's `null coalesce operator`.
It will return `$_GET['page']` unless it's `null`. In case it's null it would return default value `'home'`.

It has same meaning as:

`!is_null($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : 'home'`

Comment: Not only `is_null` but `isset` too. So if you do `echo $undefinedVar ?? 'test'` the result would be `test`